# PHP IF statement within a FOREACH loop

Tags: php

Returning to PHP after a fair few years off, just for a personal project.

I am having trouble getting an if statement to work inside a foreach loop. I am trying to get the code to echo an additional value if one of the arrays equals a certain word.

The code I have so far is:

```
$test = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');

foreach ($test as $value){  
    if ($value == "test2"){
        $secondValue = "value";
    }   

    echo $value . $secondValue . "<br />";
}
```

I was expecting this to output the following:

```
test1
test2value
test3
test4
test5
```

However it outputs this...

```
test1
test2value
test3value
test4value
test5value
```

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?
Many Thanks

Comment: Because once `$secondValue` is set, it remains set. Replace `if ($value == "test2"){
        $secondValue = "value";
    }` with something like `$secondValue = ($value == "test2") ? "value" : '';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must clear/reset the $value

```
 $test = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');

 foreach ($test as $value){  
   $secondValue ="";
   if ($value == "test2"){
      $secondValue = "value";
   }   

   echo $value . $secondValue . "<br />";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `$secondValue` back to an empty string after the loop has completed so it always has a value (literally).

```
$test = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');

foreach ($test as $value){  
    $secondValue = null;
    if ($value == "test2"){
        $secondValue = "value";
    }   

    echo $value . $secondValue . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to reset $secondValue upon each iteration.

```
$test = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');

foreach ($test as $value){  
    $secondValue = '';
    if ($value == "test2"){
        $secondValue = "value";
}   

echo $value . $secondValue . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($test as $value){  
    if ($value == "test2"){
         echo $value . $secondValue . "<br />";
    } 
   else  
    echo $value . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code , because it's a short answer.

```
$test = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5');
foreach ($test as $value){  
    echo $value . ($value == 'test2' ? 'value' : '') . "<br />";  
}
```

Comment: **Why** should he use this code? A good answer should explain what's wrong in the original code and how the answer fixes it. Don't just post code without explanation.